# I want to show a hidden in mobile format only on button click?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a filter div which is invisible in mobile format but visible in desktop. Now I want to show it in mobile on only a button click because I want to save my maximum area in mobile?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.bookfilter-container {
    display:block;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
.bookfilter-container {
display:none;
                     }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="bookfilter-container" id="bookfilter">
      my Filter goas here.
   </div>
</bod>
<html>
```

Comment: `$("#ButtonIdHere").click(function() { $(".bookfilter-container").show() });`

Comment: What's the problem of just showing it upon the button click? You should not need to worry about whether it is on mobile or desktop, no?

Comment: @ChanMT I think the OP want it hidden as default if you view hes page on Mobile, So i dont get the point of your comment.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen My comment was directed to the OP. The OP wants the filter div to be hidden by default when viewing from a mobile device (hence the media query), and show upon a button click. I assume he knows how to show a hidden element using JavaScript, so I find the question strange. Now that I think of it, maybe he actually does not know how to do that with JavaScript.

Comment: At first he sounded to me that he seems to *only* want this button to function when it is clicked on a mobile device. The button should just show the div like in your first comment. If it is on desktop, it is already shown, so nothing happens (or better yet, do not show the button at all). And if it is on mobile, it'll show the div.

Comment: I got my required output from the first comment of @CarstenLøvboAndersen.. :)
Thanks all others also !!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.bookfilter-container {
    display:block;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
.bookfilter-container {
display:none;
                     }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="click_on">Click</a>
   <div class="bookfilter-container" id="bookfilter">
      my Filter goas here.
   </div>
</bod>
<html>
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if(windowWidth <= 900px){
$(".click_on").on('click', function(){
    $(".bookfilter-container").css("display","block");
});
}
```

Comment: It is always a good idea to leave an explanation to your answer